# Xcode 11 debugger is extremely slow - A known problem?

Tags: ios, xcode

Since I updated to the latest Xcode version 11.0 (11A420a) the debugging is extremely slow and cumbersome.

**EDIT:** After updating to 11.1 GM (11A1027) the problem is still the same.

Compiling a project and running it in simulator or on a device is no problem. However when reaching a breakpoint Xcode becomes more or less unusable:

- Program execution stops immediately when the breakpoint is reached. However Xcode needs up to 30 seconds to show the position in the code window and another minute or so to load the content of the variable view (which shows the values and states of the variables available at the breakpoint).
- If I use the *Step into* or *Step over* features it takes up to a minute to perform the next step and again another minute to load the variables.

I am running Xcode on a Mac mini 2018 with a 3.2 GHz i7 and 32 GB ram. I have used Xcode 10 on the same machine before without any problems.

---

Searching for "Xcode slow" brings up a ton of threads and possible solutions of course. From my years as iOS Developer I know that Xcode never was the fastest and stable program. However it was never as bad as now.

Unfortunately none of the know tricks (restarting Xcode or the Mac, cleaning the project, cleaning the Xcode library folders, etc. had any effect,

**So the big question is:**

**Is this a known problem in Xcode 11? Are there any known solutions?**

Comment: Well for starters the latest stable version of Xcode is 11A1027, not 11A420a. I would start by updating it.

Comment: Mmh, 11A420a is the latest version available in the App Store

Comment: I have noticed the same problem while using Xcode 11A420a. Unfortunately i haven't figured out why is it happening nor if it is a known problem

Comment: The latest version was released yesterday and as always is promptly available on https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: I have now updated to 11A420a and the problem is still the same.

Comment: I tried 11.1 (11A1027) — same

Comment: @nikans Of course I meant 11A1027 in my last comment :-) So, I can confirm that 11A1027 does not make any difference.

Comment: One thing you could do is file a bug report with Apple. That is what I typically do. They eventually reply. Typically they ask for system info and requires you run some diagnostics. In general, Xcode is slow and I'm not sure Apple knows how to fix it. I'm running on an 10 core iMac Pro and Xcode is still dog slow.

Comment: xcode 11.2 (11B41) seems to be running smooth

Comment: ahhhh i'm same too it's drive me crazy. too slow

Comment: @nikans 11.2 is still beta, isn't it?

Comment: @ValerioSantinelli yep, you work in it, and build for deployment with what you have not in beta

Comment: same issue,In my case `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` is useful

Comment: Nothing to add, just a fellow sufferer. FWIW I find clean builds help but not for long. Switching thread contexts in lldb seems to aggravate the slowdown.

Comment: Can you check if your breakpoints works fine for older Xcode versions?

Comment: @AlexBlack Yes, es described in the question everthing worked fine before updating to Xcode 11. On an other machine the same project also works fine on Xcode 10. This is definitely a problem of Xcode 11.

Comment: for me it was the seed version of 11.2 from developer website.  downloading the release version of 11,.2 sorted the problem

Comment: Xcode 11.2.1 fixes a "slow debugger" issue, so if that was your problem I recommend upgrading. However, we're also finding that our build times are much much longer on Xcode 11 vs Xcode 10, and the 11.2.1 doesn't address that.

Comment: Please correct the question its not about overall slowness of Xcode but about debugger

Comment: Well, Xcode 12 beta 2 put this problem onto the whole new level. It's now basically impossible to use a "Debug executable" scheme setting, as it takes a whole minute to launch an app this way.

Comment: I've been experiencing the speed issue for a long time, but basically in my case it started with Swift. Debugging Obj-C had always been "super fast". All variables would get evaluated "instantly". Yesterday, I happened to debug a bit of Obj-C inside a mainly Swift project. All of a sudden, the debugger recovered the speed I used to know years ago. My thought is there's something fundamentally wrong with Swift debugger. Often takes 30+ seconds to evaluate variables. And if I try "step over", it can take 30s for one line...

Comment: Xcode 13.1 has the same issue.

Answer (score 39):

Well I had the same problem and recently figured out that I just forgot to disable diagnostics for my scheme

[image]

*Open your run configurations -> Manage schemes -> Edit scheme -> Run -> Diagnostics tab*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Due to the upvotes I assume that this solved the problem for some users. However, in my case it did not make any difference what so ever. So while this might help in some cases it is no general solution unfortunately

Comment: Andrei Could you provide some quantitative metrics what "became slower" means? Do you know that builds of mixed-language projects of Swift and Objective-C are generally slower?

Comment: Well I think it's all in the question... First of all this has nothing to do with build time. As written before: "Compiling a project and running it in simulator or on a device is no problem. However when reaching a breakpoint Xcode becomes more or less unusable"

Comment: Cool Andrei, but my answer about the debugger. Diagnostics page shows up debugger's settings. And there's nothing about build time. Specifically the part about memory management and allocations. Just recheck the name of your scheme and configuration.

Comment: Andrei, I don't think that you installed a custom LLDB on top of your Xcode 11 which implies the latest OS-X. It is something specific to your environment. I would recommend rechecking all scheme settings one more time.

Comment: Initial build time was 582s before and 699s after unchecking these boxes. I am not sure how this gets so many upvotes.

Comment: Travis that is a strange statement. If the build was finished before then Xcode shouldn't rebuild it at all. Sounds like there were changes in code that affected build time. The more files were changed after the last build the more build time. And by the way, the question was about debugger not build time.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen some performance improvements when using the Whole versus Incremental Compilation behavior. Additionally running on Mojave and Catalina should both be showing performance issues. Specifically since the Canvas preview and other new features require more CPU intensity than the last version of Xcode, I would expect Mojave performance to be lower when using Xcode 11 (as it's not optimized for this version of the OS). With Catalina being in Beta, I'd expect to see additional issues as well. I haven't taken specific measures other than the eye-test. The initial run on Whole Compilation is slow but seems to get better thereafter.

**Quick help states:**

> Summary
>
> This setting controls the way the Swift files in a module are rebuilt.
>   * *Incremental*: Only rebuild the Swift source files in the module that are out of date, running multiple compiler processes as needed. *
>   *Whole Module*: Always rebuild all Swift source files in the module, in a single compiler process. Declaration
>
> SWIFT_COMPILATION_MODE Value Type
>
> Enumeration (String)

Comment: Compilation time is ok, using breakpoints though teleports xcode somewhere close to the events horizon of a nearest black hole.

Comment: Even if the answer does not solve the problem described in the question, one notices that the author has made an effort. So that shouldn't be a reason for massive down votes, should it?

Comment: Incremental is actually the recommended setting in debug builds  now (see WWDC talk https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/408/). Maybe this depends on a project to project basis but on ours a clean build was slightly slower (5s) than a whole module build but about 40% (30s) faster for incremental builds.

Comment: @nikans the compilation time it's still to slow comparing with any other IDE and other languages. But i've to admit the worst it's the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (XCode 11.x, MacOS 10.15.2) I've found that the extreme debugger slowness is only triggered if I single-step *while another single-step operation is in progress*, i.e. I press the step button too quickly. My current workaround is to avoid doing that.

Pure speculation but perhaps it's triggered by XCode/LLDB trying to service multiple breakpoints concurrently? Try removing all breakpoints but one and see if that helps things.

In case it's relevant: I mostly work with C++ in XCode, with a little Obj-C here and there. I don't use Swift at all at present.

Answer (score 1):

For me, deleting `~/.lldb` solved this problem.

Comment: What's in lldb that makes it perform better?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running Xcode in safe mode?  It's not ideal, but this was the only way I could get it to run efficiently.  That is until the recent Catalina update where my device is no longer detected in safe mode.  So I'm back to square one now.

Comment: Turns out it was my antivirus software slowing things down.  Disabling it solved the problem.

Comment: @beefon I believe that Dino was referring to the MacOs safe mode. You can read more about it here: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262

Answer (score 0):

I've found the same problems in two different cases:

1) the app is not launched by Xcode, i.e. the flag "Wait for executable to be launched" is set inside the Info panel of the Scheme Run settings;

2) the option "Launch due to a background fetch event" is selected in the scheme settings (but this is not the default)

[image: Xcode option position]

Xcode 11.2.1 (11B500)

Answer (score 0):

Please try to uncheck: **Parallelize Build** on each target in **Edit Scheme**. It 'll save time to build If your project has many targets.

Edit Scheme:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've been dealing with this forever and finally figured it out. It was these lines in my ~/.lldbinit file:

```
break set -F '-[UIView layoutIfNeeded]' -c '!(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread]' -L objc
break set -F '-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) updateConstraintsIfNeeded]' -c '!(BOOL)[NSThread isMainThread]' -L objc
```

I commented those lines out and now it's almost as fast as without the debugger!

Comment: Interesting. Can you explain what those lines do themselves?

Comment: They were intended to catch layout actions in a non-main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I had 238 unused breakpoints set. When I deleted them, it's fast again (even with diagnostics turned on.)

Comment: Same problem and solution. Even though my breakpoints are disabled (i had 1280), somehow they still cause this issue.

Answer (score -1):

In my case,
When I switched to cellular network the problem was resolved.