# Xcode 11 Debugger Extremely Slow

Tags: xcode11

Since downloading Xcode 11, I have noticed that setting breakpoints, stepping into and over code, that the debugger tends to hang, sometimes for minutes at a time. I cannot imagine that Apple would release something like this so I assume I have some misplaced configuration setting or something. Has anybody else noticed this? If so, is there a fix? Surely I am not the only person who has ran into this problem.

Comment: Just to be more specific I am running OSX 10.14.6, Xcode 11.0 (11A420a). I have tested on both simulator and multiple devices running iOS 11, 12 and 13.

Comment: I have a mac mini that I use as a backup, I am updating it to all the latest stuff and will test to see if it too is very slow. My 32gb i7 Macbook Pro, has fried the system board 3 times in the less than a year that I have had it, so I am thinking it could actually be a hardware problem.

Comment: Having a nice little conversation with myself. I updated my mac mini to the same exact environment as my mac book pro. The debugger is also nearly unusable there as well. I guess I will wait and see if anybody else is experiencing this problem. Hard to believe nobody out there is using Xcode 11 and debugging.

Comment: I have found this same problem as well. I haven't test it myself but I have read it should be solved in Xcode 11.2.
Also, based on my experience the problem with slow debugging only happens in fairly big projects, small ones work just fine

Comment: Some of this may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095866/xcode-11-extremly-slow-a-known-problem

Comment: Same issue here on 11.1

Comment: My project is 548 source files, that probably qualifies as pretty big. I will try 11.2, thanks!

Comment: I updated to Catalina and xcode 11.1. It seems to be slightly faster, but not much. You can still wait upwards of 2 minutes by simply stepping over a line. Seems totally random. Having trouble getting 3rd party software to link on 11.2, but will get there eventually and comment accordingly here.

Comment: I noticed that my old projects that are using Objective-C debug just fine. But when I use Swift it debugs really slowly. _(XCode 11.0 - MacOS Catalina)_

Comment: I also have the latest OSX (Catalina) on a Mac Mini 2012 and Xcode 11.1. Debugging is very slow, especially on the first breakpoint hit. After that it runs better. So after every first breakpoint hit, it takes like 15 sec. or more to get back.

Comment: I now have XCode 11.2. Nikano suggested that it solved the problem. However, it is still very slow on all of our computers. I believe no improvement at all. Again, this is a very large project, one of the biggest on the app store, Xcode does not seem to be able to manage that very well. I have a bug in with Apple Developer, awaiting reply. Stay Tuned.

Comment: @PDG What is the Radar number for this issue ?

Comment: We originally tried to use Apple Developer Technical Support. They want us now to submit a bug report, here is the latest from Apple:

Comment: Thank you for contacting Apple Developer Technical Support (DTS). We have reviewed your request and believe this issue would be best handled by the relevant engineering team directly, as it may require changes to the OS, tools, or the frameworks you are using. 

Please submit a complete bug report regarding this issue ....

Comment: I have never used Feedback assistant, I will let you know when I have submitted, will probably try tonight.

Comment: There was a problem where every step could take ~15 seconds, which was fixed in Xcode 11.2.  There are (relatively) expensive operations taken on the first expression and sometimes the first step in a debug session, but if you're seeing debugger slowness for e.g. the SECOND expression or SECOND step, please do file a report with Feedback assistant -- most importantly, if you can start `sample lldb-rpc-server` while the slowness is happening, it will likely move the investigation along a lot faster.  (I'm not saying the first expression/step shouldn't be faster!  but it's a different category)

Comment: Xcode 11.2.1 has fixed the slowness problem. We still encountered the problem on 11.2. We filed a bug with Feedback Assistant and they replied to confirm that 11.2.1 fixed the issue, which it did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 11.2.1 was the fix provided by Apple

Comment: Don't think so, Its still irritatingly slow

Comment: Does it take minutes to step between lines for you? Or is it just a little slow, 2 seconds to step over?

Comment: It takes 10 or so seconds to response once it reaches the breakpoint. Its like Xcode is  frozen.

Comment: I am sorry to ask this, but you are on version 11.2.1?

Comment: Yes. Exactly 11.2.1

Comment: Then you need to submit a bug with Apple. Go to Apple Developer and do it there. Please let us know how this is resolved. Thanks.