# Xcode constantly hangs on break points in a large project

Tags: xcode, debugging, breakpoints

In one of my projects, **Xcode constantly hangs on every break point** for at least a minute before responding. It only happens on that specific project which is fairly large, and has around 60 pods.

I tried restarting Xcode/my machine, deleting `derivedData` but no luck.

It's happening on `Xcode 11.1`, `Xcode 11` and `Xcode 10`.

**How would you suggest to debug this?**

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095866/xcode-11-extremely-slow-a-known-problem ?

Comment: Thanks @matt, it's the same issue but I'm seeing it on Xcode 10 as well with that specific project.

Comment: Yes, and you can see from that question that there's no definitive cure. I don't think this is something Stack Overflow can help with. You should file a bug report with Apple...

Comment: Yes, tried that as well, no response yet. Just because I'm only seeing it with a single project, I was wondering if there're suggestions to how to debug such an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen breakpoints be slow (15 to 30 seconds, especially waiting for the variables view to stop spinning and appear).  It seems especially bad in Xcode 11.  I've also heard the same issues on some iOS podcasts in past few weeks (e.g. MTJC).

So here are some further ideas (beyond the ones you mentioned) that might just fix it for you:

1. Remove all existing breakpoints before adding your new breakpoint.
2. Avoid use of breakpoints
   that have "Automatically continue after evaluating actions".
3. Avoid using other features of breakpoints... just use plain ole
   simple breakpoints.
4. Avoid using breakpoints in tight loops of
   code.

Comment: Thank you for these ideas @Smartcat! However, I'm afraid the issue is still happening.

Comment: Yeah, figured it would be, but was worth a shot. I believe these points can help to some degree in at least some situations, though - both from some personal experience and what I've heard others discussing recently.  The crux of the issue, though, is Apple's tooling needs to catch up to Swift 5.