# Weird behaviour of Xcode 11 Debugger - Showing values as nil when there's a value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10, xcode11

I just noticed weird behaviour of Xcode11, I am executing same code in Xcode 10 and Xcode 11.

See the below attached screenshot for both the versions.

I am creating a url from String, When I put a debugger and check the value of myUrl it shows nil although at very next line it passes nil check and control goes into the not nil case.

See the console too.

have anyone already faced this type of issue? or I am doing something wrong.

P.S: Already Cleared cache, derived data, clean build, restart Xcode. don't confuse with the breakpoint's location, both are captured with different system.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you please clarify? The breakpoints seem to be at different positions in your examples. I guess the left one shows up as `nil` because is breaking just before assignment (?)

Comment: They both are from different system and different project with Xcode 11 and Xcode 10. Please updated question

Comment: Sorry, just realised that you have stepped to line 25. Yes that seems like a bug (or an optimisation as per @jalone 's answer).

Comment: Digging deeper this is actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108824/instantiated-optional-variable-shows-as-nil-in-xcode-debugger

Comment: I am getting an inverse issue where the debugger shows value as nil when doing `po variable` but the Xcode UI shows it as not nil.

Answer (score 8):

This is a known bug, affecting LLDB (the Xcode debugger) as well as the REPL. It's purely a matter of display:

https://github.com/apple/llvm-project/issues/4477

https://github.com/apple/llvm-project/issues/4479

And see:

[Instantiated optional variable shows as nil in Xcode debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58108824/instantiated-optional-variable-shows-as-nil-in-xcode-debugger)

An easy workaround for now is to pass thru the bridged Objective C type. The bug is only with the Swift Foundation overlay type. So in this case just cast to NSURL.

So for example:

[image]

But:

[image]

**This bug is slated to be fixed in Xcode 12.5.**

Comment: I have taken the liberty to update the broken bug links, apparently they are not redirected automatically to GitHub issues. I hope that I got them right.

Comment: @MartinR Cool, thanks for doing that; I forgot all about the Big Move.

Comment: These *should* be redirected automatically. For example, https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5046 is redirected to https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/47622. But it does not work with your “plugins/servlet/mobile” links.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using an answer since for the comment would be too long, but
>   would be more appropriate.

I am currently (catalina, xcode 11.1) facing many similar issues, beside a general slow down of the debugger.

To be sure anyway:

- check that in the target build settings the compile time optimization is disabled for debug: Optimization Level -O0 (the var may be optimized away)
- this solved some of my issues as well (disabling the diagnostic made lldb a bit faster and solved issues with p/po and collecting the stacktrace): [Xcode 11 extremely slow - A known problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095866/xcode-11-extremely-slow-a-known-problem)

Comment: This did not seem relevant at least in my case. All those flags and settings were properly set up