# Can't assign one struct to another in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, struct

I'm stuck with some kind of stupid thing ))
Can't assign one struct to another in tableview cell.
This is assignment:
[image]

As you can see, in

> func setFormElement

element is not empty and has some values. But immediately after assignment without any errors

> formElement

is still nil? Why? Can't understand.
This is WebFormElement struct:
[image]

Getting the cell and calling "initialize":
[image]

TableView method:
[image]
Don’t pay attention to the error - I reduced the "switch" for comfortable reading.

Thanks for help!

Comment: It might just be delayed due to code optimization. Does it show if you break inside of setBorders()? Or when you return from setFormElement?

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855037/weird-behaviour-of-xcode-11-debugger-showing-values-as-nil-when-theres-a-valu

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly in your code are you calling `func setFormElement`?

When reproducing your issue in the Xcode playground with a very simplified example:

```
import UIKit

class MessageRowWebFormCell {
    var formElement: WebFormElement? = nil

    func setFormElement(element: WebFormElement) {
        formElement = element
    }
}

struct WebFormElement {
    var myString = "hello world"
}

let someInstance = MessageRowWebFormCell()
let someStruct = WebFormElement()
someInstance.setFormElement(element: someStruct)

print(someInstance.formElement)
```

The console actually prints "Optional(__lldb_expr_45.WebFormElement(myString: "hello world"))", i.e. `formElement` was properly set and there seems to be no issue at all.

Therefore, probably there is more information required to tackle your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason, as I think.
Today I updated my iMac and XCode tools have been updated too.
If I print some values from my "formElement", they looks ok. But debugger cannot find it.

Comment: There is an LLDB / REPL bug where Swift structs that are not nil are shown as nil. I thought it was only Foundation overlay structs but maybe not.