# lldb optional Date it's never nil

Tags: swift, date, llvm, lldb

Can someone explain me why the lldb when printing a Date optional passed as nil doesn't print nil.

I declared a function which receives optional Date:

```
override func setup() {
    super.setup()

    optionalFooTest(startDate: nil, endDate: nil)
}

func optionalFooTest(startDate: Date?, endDate: Date?) {

    if startDate == nil {

        let foo = "foo"
    }
}
```

The behaviour is it will enter in the if but the lldb when I print the startDate it gives me a value or when i test if it's nil.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855037/weird-behaviour-of-xcode-11-debugger-showing-values-as-nil-when-theres-a-valu) looks related which suggests this is a bug in lldb

Comment: Yep it's seems about right, let's wait a little bit more and if nobody see's another possibility i will ask you to give this as answer.

Comment: Try printing the value of startDate then and see what it shows.

Comment: Is it the same for `v startDate`?

Comment: This is the same issue.  This problem effects any swift algorithmic enum whose current payload is a "resilient" type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@Joakim Danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) mentioned in comments this is the bug in lldb mentioned [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58855037/weird-behaviour-of-xcode-11-debugger-showing-values-as-nil-when-theres-a-valu) i was thinking the problem was the struct Date but it's not, it's the lldb itself.