# Why Bool? in Xcode debugger is displayed as nil when it is not?

Tags: swift, xcode

In Xcode 14.1 when debugger displays Bool?, it is always as nil, no matter what is inside.
So this in code:

```
let v1: Bool? = nil
let v2: Bool? = true
let v3: Bool = true
```

is displayed as:

```
(Bool?) v1 = nil
(Bool?) v2 = nil
(Bool) v3 = true
```

When using "po v2" it displays it correctly as:

```
▿ Optional<Bool>
  - some : true
```

Can someone explain?

Comment: Looks like a bug. Similar issues were reported here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58855037/1187415, and here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58108824/1187415

Comment: @MartinR At the time, I thought the issue was limited to Foundation overlay types such as Data and URL. I'm surprised to learn that it applies also to simple Bool. I don't know whether that was also true at the time and now I have no way to find out. :)

Comment: @matt: Yes, I though so as well, I and don't know if this is a new bug or not. But I can reproduce it with Xcode 14.1.

Comment: Here is another report: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698633

Comment: @MartinR Yes, agreed.