# Why Swift is so slow in Debug mode

Tags: ios, swift, performance, debug-mode

I realized Swift is very slow then Objective-C in Debug mode. I am using Xcode 11.

The objective-c test code:

```
@interface TestTests : XCTestCase
@end
@implementation TestTests
- (void)testExample {
    [self measureBlock:^{
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i ++) {
            [self emptyFunction];
        }
    }];
}
- (void)emptyFunction
{
}
@end
```

The swift test code:

```
class InterestTests: XCTestCase {
    func testExample() {
        self.measure {
            for _ in 1 ... 1000000 {
                self.empty()
            }
        }
    }
    func empty() {

    }
}
```

### In release mode.

Objective-C spends an average of **0.00262**s

[image]

Swift spends an average of **0.0000135**s

[image]

In release mode. Swift is 0.00262/0.0000135= **194** times faster than Objective-C.

### In debug mode.

Objective-C spends an average of **0.00525**s. Debug is 0.00525/0.00262= **2** times slower than Release for Objective-C

[image]

Swift spends an average of **0.664**s. Debug is 0.664/0.0000135= **49185** times slower than Release for Swift!!!

[image]

In Debug mode. Swift is 0.664/0.00525= **126** times slower than Objective-C!!!

Why swift is so slow in Debug mode?

Comment: checkout this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58095866/xcode-11-debugger-is-extremely-slow-a-known-problem

Comment: check this as well - https://medium.com/@joshgare/8-tips-to-speed-up-your-swift-build-and-compile-times-in-xcode-73081e1d84ba

Comment: @DeepakTerse I see. Thanks!.